# Copy and paste row to closed workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to be able to select a row and copy & paste it (With a command button) to a closed workbook that remains closed. The code below copies everything below a range. I just want to copy the row I have selected.

These are the lines that need to be changed:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With .Range(.Range("A4:Q4"), .Range("A4:Q4").End(xlDown))
destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
```

The full code:

```
Sub copytoarchive()
Dim destSht As Worksheet
Workbooks.Open ("C:\...\FileToCopyTo.xlsx") 
Set destSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3") 
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With .Range(.Range("A4:Q4"), .Range("A4:Q4").End(xlDown))
destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value 
End With
End With
destSht.Parent.Close True 
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to edit a file, you need to open it. You can close it again after it is saved.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: well, you said you wanted to paste data into a closed workbook that remains closed - you do need to open it if you want to paste data in

Comment: Yes, that I know. The issue is this code copies several ranges. I just want to copy the row I have selected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
Sub copytoarchive()
Dim destSht As Worksheet

Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Open ("C:\...\FileToCopyTo.xlsx")
Set destSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

destSht.Activate
Range("A1").Select
destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

destSht.Parent.Close True

End Sub
```

It copies, opens the target sheet, finds the next row the way you were doing it already, then pastes and closes.

Comment: Its giving me an error for line Range("A1").Select